# C++. How to write to file from function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I have function what must write something in file.

I try it this way:

```
int main() {
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");
    i = searchLexemes(input, i, 1, fout);
}
```

searchLexemes is defined this way:

```
int searchLexemes(std::string value, int i, int type, std::ofstream fout);
```

If i call searchLexemes like i do in main(), Visual Studio gives me error:

> IntelliSense: "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,
>   _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [с _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (объявлено в строке 1034 из "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\fstream")
>   недоступно    c:\Users\Badina\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PLT
>   lab1\PLT lab1\Исходный код.cpp    191 33  PLT lab1

I'm using russian version of VS 2012, but i guess problem must be clear.

Comment: take `fout` by reference, `std::ofstream& fout`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `reference` to declare your function like so:

```
int searchLexemes(const std::string& value, int i, int type, std::ofstream& fout);
```

The reason you've got this error is because `std::ofstream` does not have a public copy constructor (eg: `ofstream(const ofstream& rhs)`), or one is explicitly marked as `delete`d in C++11.

Answer (score -1):

You should have the function call fout.open, pass in the name of the file.

But if you really want to then,

```
int searchLexemes(std::string value, int i, int type, std::ofstream *fout);
int main() {
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");
    i = searchLexemes(input, i, 1, &fout);
}
```

Comment: A pointer is a type of variable. What you need to pass in is the address of the fout, that is why you need to use &. This address your passing in can only be recognized by your function definition as a pointer type variable. In that way when the function modifies the fout, the one in your main will change. As your telling the function to access that memory. Otherwise, when you pass in a variable normally, the function makes a copy of it for itself.

Comment: As simple reference `std::ofstream &fout` in the function signature would do as well, and makes the implementation code for the `searchLexemes()` easier to write and read.

Comment: Downvoted because the code here has memory leaks (as `fout` isn't `delete`d).

Comment: @cybermonkey Nonsense, nothing leaks. The `fout` never was creadted with `new`. If you downvote, have valid reasons.